# Trimming email address to hide the name

Tags: java, strings, email

I am looking to hide an email id name, by only showing first 4 letters of the email. The code works fine. Looking for opinion if I could make it better, more readable and maybe even more efficient if possible. I am using Commons lang library for this and wondering if that is an unnecessary overhead.

Please look for the comment `<-- HERE -->`. I am looking for opinion in this region. I am using Java 7, no way around that.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //all these prints out as expected.

        String newEmail1 = getEmail("sample1");
        System.out.println("Expected: some**@gmail.com | actual: " + newEmail1);

        String newEmail2 = getEmail("sample2");
        System.out.println("Expected: null | actual: " + newEmail2);

        String newEmail3 = getEmail("short");
        System.out.println("Expected: q**@gmail.com | actual: " + newEmail3);

        String newEmail4 = getEmail("noname");
        System.out.println("Expected: null | actual: " + newEmail4);
    }

    private static String getEmail(String param){
        //added these solely for testing to show
        Map<String, String> emails = new HashMap<>();
        emails.put("sample1", "someone@gmail.com");
        emails.put("short", "qw@gmail.com");
        emails.put("noname", "@gmail.com");
        //added these solely for testing to show

        //I am looking for opinions from here onwards. <-- HERE -->
        String emailAddress = emails.get(param);
        if(emailAddress != null){
            String emailAddressFront = StringUtils.substringBefore(emailAddress, "@");
            String emailAddressBack = StringUtils.substringAfter(emailAddress, "@");

            // i need to hide emails by only revealing first 4 characters.
            // but also need to check in case email name is shorter than 4.
            if(emailAddressFront.isEmpty()){
                return null;
            }
            int shortenedLength = 4;
            int emailNameLength = emailAddressFront.length();
            if(emailNameLength < 4){
                shortenedLength = emailNameLength - 1;
            }
            emailAddress = emailAddressFront.substring(0, shortenedLength) + "**@" + emailAddressBack;
        }
        return emailAddress;
        //I am looking for opinions till here. <-- HERE -->
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's a `java.mail.internet.InternetAddress` class that may do the email parsing you want (ie can return just the front). I found [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) for Java EE 7, can't find anything newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guard clauses are easier to read than nested blocks.

It will be somewhat more efficient to track the index of the `@` sign rather than using substrings. You definitely don’t need Apache commons.

Try not to reassign variables if you can help it. In this case, you can leverage a StringBuilder to mutate your email address into a new String. The `replace` method is particularly applicable.

Using the above ideas, you could change your code to look more like:

```
private static String getEmail(final String param){
    final Map<String, String> emails = new HashMap<>();
    emails.put("sample1", "someone@gmail.com");
    emails.put("short", "qw@gmail.com");
    emails.put("noname", "@gmail.com");

    final String emailAddress = emails.get(param);
    if (emailAddress == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final int atIndex = emailAddress.indexOf('@');
    if (atIndex == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    final StringBuilder maskedEmailAddress = new StringBuilder(emailAddress);
    if (atIndex < 4) {
        maskedEmailAddress.replace(1, atIndex, "**");
    } else {
        maskedEmailAddress.replace(4, atIndex, "**");
    }

    return maskedEmailAddress.toString();
}
```